# data-src not getting replaced with src after jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am binding a div with a response from ajax function like below

```
BindProductFamilyList: function (str) {
    var _obj= new Object();

    _obj.id= str;


    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.aspx/Bind',
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'obj': _obj}),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#divLoader").fadeIn();
        },
        complete: function () {
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var _strInnerHtml = "";
            $("#div").html(_strInnerHtml);
            // Loop and bind the parameter header
            $.each(response, function (key, value) {
                if (Object.keys(value).length > 0) {
                    $.each(value, function (key, value) {
                        // Loop and bind 
                        _strInnerHtml += "<div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-5'>";
                        _strInnerHtml += "<a href='#' title='View Details'class='prod-box wow fadeInUp'>"; 
                        _strInnerHtml += "<img class='img-fluid'  src='data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs='  data-src='../uploads/pic/" + value.pic + "' title='" + value.name + "' alt='" + value.name + "' />";
                        _strInnerHtml += "<h2>" + value.name + "</h2>";
                        _strInnerHtml += "</a>";
                        _strInnerHtml += "</div>";
                    });
                }
                else {

                    _strInnerHtml = "No records.";
                }
            });
            $("#div").html(_strInnerHtml);
            $("#divLoader").fadeOut();

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //alert(xhr.status);
            //alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}



  $(document).on("change", ".catfilter", function () {
    ns.BindProductFamilyList(ns.GetSelectedId());
});
```

First time on calling this function, the images are loaded properly. When I call this function on change event of checkbox list. The images are not loading, only the data 64 image is loaded and the actual image from the folder is not loaded. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try adding an img.onLoad event and set the img.src as the result of that event instead....

`img.onload(function(){img.src = "imgurl.png"})`

Comment: Thank you.. Could you please elaborate on where I should include this, in the above code?